# How to get more info on error during clone?

Tags: aegir

When cloning one of my sites I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations
>   (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for
>   operation '=' 
>   - error

I am unsure how to find where this is happening. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an SQL error and not an Aegir one so I'd recommend searching for that error specifically.  However, the conventional way to get more output for a failed Aegir task would be to run the following on the CLI:

```
drush @hostmaster hosting-task --force --verbose --debug TASK_ID
```